# Confusion about cohomology groups $H^i(S_3,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $S_3$ be the third symmetric group and let it act trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the following theorem on page $154$ of Brown *Group Cohomology*

> **(9.1) Theorem** The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i) $G$ has periodic cohomology,
>
> (ii) There exist $n,d$ with $d\neq 0$ such that $\hat{H}^n(G,M)\simeq \hat{H}^{n+d}(G,M)$ for all $G$-modules $M$,
>
> (iii) For some $d\neq 0$, $\hat{H}^d(G,\mathbb{Z})\simeq|G|^{-1}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z},$
>
> (iv) For some $d\neq 0$, $\hat{H}^d(G,\mathbb{Z})$ contains an element of order $|G|$.

I was interested in investigating whether or not $S_3$ has periodic cohomology. To this end, I calculated $H^2(S_3,\mathbb{Z})$. Note that by an explicit description of $H^1(G,M)$, we have $H^1(A_3,\mathbb{Z})=0$. Since $H^1(A_3,\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes, we have the following inflation-restriction exact sequence (see [proposition 1.6.7](https://imgur.com/a/CND1bP6) of *Cohomology of Number Fields.*)

$$0\to H^2(S_3/A_3,\mathbb{Z})\to H^2(S_3,\mathbb{Z})\to H^2(A_3,\mathbb{Z})\to H^3(S_3/A_3,\mathbb{Z})$$

By periodicity of cyclic cohomology, we have $H^2(S_3/A_3,\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $H^2(A_3,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, and $H^3(A_3,\mathbb{Z})=0$, so we have

$$0\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to H^2(S_3,\mathbb{Z})\to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$

which implies by classification of finitely generated abelian groups yields $H^2(S_3,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. This means that $S_3$ satisfies (iii) in theorem 9.1 of Brown, and so $S_3$ should have periodic cohomology.

However, $\hat{H}^{-2}(S_3,\mathbb{Z})=Ab(S_3)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where $Ab(G)$ is the abelianization of $G$, but as we've shown $\hat{H}^2(S_3,\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\not\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\simeq \hat{H}^{-2}(S_3,\mathbb{Z})$, so the cohomology cannot be $2$-periodic. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Can you quote this proposition 1.6.7? I checked my copy (assuming it's the right book) and it's not in there.

Comment: I'm guessing this is inflation-restriction, in which case you're missing the $S_3$ action on $H^2(A_3)$.

Comment: @Steve D Here's a [link](https://imgur.com/a/CND1bP6) to a picture of proposition 1.6.7 in my copy of Cohomology of number fields. As for the $S_3$ action, because $S_3$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$, the $S_3$ action on $H^2(A_3)$ is also trivial and it's invariance is all of $H^2(A_3)$.

Comment: I calculated it another way, using the exact sequence $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and got $\mathbb{Z}/2$, but I'm still not exactly sure what the issue with the argument in my post is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that the action of $S_3$ on $H^2(A_3)$ is trivial: the action is induced by conjugation. If we conjugate with a $2$-cycle, we get the inversion map on $A_3$. From this, via an explicit description of the conjugation map on cocycles, it's not difficult to figure out that the action is nontrivial. Hence the invariants are zero and we get that $H^2(S_3) \cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.